# Two shareholder agreements in parallel

Tags: corporate-law, shareholders

I am looking to receive an investment from an accelerator (investor A) and from a private investor (investor B). I have draft shareholder agreements with both investors A and B.

My lawyer is telling me that I cannot have two shareholder agreements in parallel. When a shareholder agreement comes after an existing one, it should either invalidate the first or amend it.

Is that correct? Can I have two shareholder agreements in parallel?